# Post request errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-onetomany

i'm basically trying to establish a onetomany relationship between two entities, when i log in to my h-2 console, i can see that the relationship has been established and i can enter the values without any problem, but when i try a post request through postman it shows me a bunch of errors.

Code for my Item Class

```
package com.itemWithData.Item;
import com.itemWithData.Category.Category;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table


public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "itemID")
    private String itemID;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemStatus;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category category;
    public Item() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Item(String itemID, String itemName, String itemStatus, Category category) {
        super();
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemStatus = itemStatus;
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }
    public void setItemID(String itemID) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getItemStatus() {
        return itemStatus;
    }
    public void setItemStatus(String itemStatus) {
        this.itemStatus = itemStatus;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    
}
```

Code for my Category Class

```
package com.itemWithData.Category;
import java.util.List;

import com.itemWithData.Item.Item;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    private Integer categoryID;
    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryDescription;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Item> items;
public Category() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Category(Integer categoryID, String categoryName, String categoryDescription, List<Item> items) {
    super();
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
    this.items = items;
}
public Integer getCategoryID() {
    return categoryID;
}
public void setCategoryID(Integer categoryID) {
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
}
public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}
public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
public String getCategoryDescription() {
    return categoryDescription;
}
public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
}
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}
public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}


}
```

this is the error i'm getting when i try a post request
[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZTl1.png)